# Question about taxability of fellowships in academia

Tags: united-states, taxes, education

I asked a similar question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194651/paying-taxes-for-a-postdoc-fellowship-when-theres-no-withholdings?noredirect=1#comment527970_194651) and was redirected to this site. I am a postdoctoral trainee (not a student) on a fellowship at a US university. I have no documentation of my fellowship money other than my paystub and a stipend letter. I will receive no tax forms for this, which I verified with my benefits office. They won't otherwise advise me on taxes. My paystub indicates a "Stipend for Health Allowance" and a "Stipend for Living Expenses". All of the former goes to my health insurance and some of the latter as well. My net income is exactly the same as before the fellowship, but 8-10x more money is allocated toward health insurance, again most of it from the "Stipend for Health Allowance". Paying taxes on that former stipend would therefore seem to me to be punitive. Can someone please clarify this situation? Apparently, this is common at my university.

Comment: This is related, does it answer your question? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/156116/reporting-wage-income-not-on-w2

Comment: Thanks. It's related, but I am specifically talking about my health insurance amount that is built into my gross pay as I mention, and that is 8x higher (for exactly the same health insurance) as before the fellowship, hence my confusion.

Comment: Perhaps the health insurance amount isn't taxable? Am I reading this right? https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/employee-benefits

Comment: what exactly are you reading there?

Comment: "If an employer pays the cost of an accident or health insurance plan for his/her employees (including an employee's spouse and dependents), then the employer's payments are not wages and are not subject to social security, Medicare, and FUTA taxes, or federal income tax withholding." I am wondering if that applies here.

Comment: Are you employed? Is the employer paying your health insurance? From your question it sounds like the answer to both of those is "no".

Comment: @littleadv the answer to both of those is actually yes - I am employed. My employer is paying me via this fellowship. The fellowship includes health insurance as I have been trying to clarify.

Comment: We're speaking in different terms. You're not employed, you're a post-doc fellow. It's a fellowship, not an employment. Your university doesn't pay for your health insurance, it provides stipend *to you*, and *you* are the one actually paying for health insurance. I know it may sounds to you like a semantic difference, but it matters.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to matter for these purposes. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As covered in [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/156122/2998), postdoc fellowship grants are taxable income in the US.

> My net income is exactly the same as before the fellowship, but 8-10x more money is allocated toward health insurance, again most of it from the "Stipend for Health Allowance". Paying taxes on that former stipend would therefore seem to me to be punitive

Welcome to the US. If you're a US taxpayer, you could deduct health-related expenses on your Form 1040 Schedule A line 1. If you are not a US taxpayer (you're filing 1040NR) then you cannot deduct these expenses.

The income in either way is taxable.

Comment: +1 Thanks. And so that I understand, I can definitely deduct the health-related expense, but is it at all an issue that the amount I'm paying for health insurance according to my paystub as mentioned is much higher than what's on the 1095-C? (I wonder if it's an issue there's no way I have to "prove" my income apart from my paystub and stipend letter.)

Comment: @user2561523 is it a deduction on your paystub, and it doesn't match 1095-C? I'd ask your employer and insurer.

Comment: Yeah, I did. They say it "reports the lowest plan option available to you at employee only coverage". This is so strange!

Comment: @user2561523 yup, that matches what the form says: "*This line reports the employee required contribution, which is the monthly cost to you for the
lowest cost self-only minimum essential coverage providing minimum value that your employer offered
you*". Since you're not actually employed, you should be able to deduct what you actually paid.

Comment: And just to clarify, that would be what I actually paid for health insurance only? Other types of insurance like dental, AD&D, and life aren't deductible?

Comment: Go through the Schedule A instructions: https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sca#en_US_2022_publink53061xd0e149

Comment: @user2561523 this is schedule A for residents (form 1040), you didn't mention your immigration status, but you said that you can definitely deduct it, so I'm assuming you're a US tax resident. It may not be so if you're on J1 visa.